# Is there any way to set limit on Autodesk Forge Credit consumption?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I want to make sure that my app do not accidentally consume more credits than I can afford. How can I set such limits of weekly or monthly consumption?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately billing cap is not yet possible so you will need to calculate your own spending per the pricing info [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing) in combination with your own metering (see some open source projects [here](https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=meter+request&type=Repositories)).

Will let Engineering know it is good to have the budgeting feature soon as possible and update this answer when it’s available.